Can't place a ship part next to another part
I started working on a project in C# using Windows Forms, making a sea battle game.
How my game works:
When the program starts, a dialog is displayed where we have two options:

Player vs player
Player vs computer

After that dialog, another dialog appears where we choose one of the following as the dimensions do we want the fields to be when we place the ships

4x4
8x8
10x10

Then, after that selection, a dialog appears with the display of those fields and it looks like this:
For example I chose 4x4:

I will give an example and what is the output:
I choose a 4x4 field for placing ships (one size 1 ship and two size 2 ships are placed on a 4x4 field)
First I was offered a size 1 ship.
I set it at the following coordinates i=0, j=0 (i is a column, j is a row)

Then after that it's the turn of the size 2 ship, and now I need to place that ship.
I place the first part of the ship at i = 2, j =0, and place it successfully.

Then I try to place another part of that ship (size 2) at i = 2, j =1, unsuccessfully it says "you cannot place a part of the ship at this position try again"

I also try to set that other part of the ship to i = 3, j = 0, but it still fails.

I've been trying to solve the problem for an hour now, but I don't know where the error/bug is and why it's not working.
Here is the code of that class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace oop_template
{
    public partial class ShipPlacementForm : Form
    {
        private int tableSize;
        private List<Ship> ships;
        private List<Ship> placedShips;
        private Button[,] tableButtons;
        private int currentShipIndex;
        private Ship currentShip;
        private bool horizontalPlacement;

        public List<Ship> PlacedShips
        {
            get { return placedShips; }
        }

        public ShipPlacementForm(int tableSize, List<Ship> ships)
        {
            this.tableSize = tableSize;
            this.ships = ships;
            this.placedShips = new List<Ship>();
            CustomInitializeComponent();

            // Initialize placement of the first ship
            this.currentShipIndex = 0;
            SetCurrentShip();
            deleteButton.Enabled = false; // Disable delete until at least one ship is placed
        }

        private void CustomInitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();

            // Dynamically create buttons for the table fields
            tableButtons = new Button[tableSize, tableSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < tableSize; j++)
                {
                    tableButtons[i, j] = new Button();
                    tableButtons[i, j].Size = new Size(30, 30);
                    tableButtons[i, j].Location = new Point(30 * i, 30 * j);
                    tableButtons[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(TableButton_Click);
                    this.Controls.Add(tableButtons[i, j]);
                }
            }

            // Label for displaying the current ship
            this.currentShipLabel = new Label();
            this.currentShipLabel.Location = new Point(30 * tableSize, 30);
            this.currentShipLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.Controls.Add(this.currentShipLabel);

            // Button for confirmation
            this.confirmButton = new Button();
            this.confirmButton.Text = "Confirm";
            this.confirmButton.Location = new Point(30 * tableSize, 60);
            this.confirmButton.Click += new EventHandler(ConfirmButton_Click);
            this.confirmButton.Enabled = false; // Disabled until all ships are placed
            this.Controls.Add(this.confirmButton);

            // Button for deleting a ship
            this.deleteButton = new Button();
            this.deleteButton.Text = "Delete Ship";
            this.deleteButton.Location = new Point(30 * tableSize, 90);
            this.deleteButton.Click += new EventHandler(DeleteButton_Click);
            this.deleteButton.Enabled = false; // Disabled until at least one ship is placed
            this.Controls.Add(this.deleteButton);

            // Set form size
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(30 * (tableSize + 2), 30 * tableSize);
            this.Name = "ShipPlacementForm";
            this.Text = "Ship Placement";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
        }

        private void TableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
            if (clickedButton == null)
                return;

            int x = clickedButton.Location.X / 30;
            int y = clickedButton.Location.Y / 30;

            if (CanPlaceShipPart(x, y))
            {
                PlaceShipPart(x, y);
                currentShip.Positions.Add(new Point(x, y));

                if (currentShip.Positions.Count == 1)
                {
                    // First part of the ship is placed, wait for the second part to determine orientation
                    deleteButton.Enabled = false; // Disable deletion until the entire ship is placed
                }
                else if (currentShip.Positions.Count == 2)
                {
                    // Determine the orientation of the ship based on the first two positions
                    horizontalPlacement = currentShip.Positions[0].Y == currentShip.Positions[1].Y;
                }

                // Check if the ship is complete
                if (currentShip.Positions.Count == currentShip.Size)
                {
                    placedShips.Add(currentShip);
                    currentShipIndex++;

                    if (currentShipIndex < ships.Count)
                    {
                        SetCurrentShip();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentShipLabel.Text = "All ships are placed.";
                        confirmButton.Enabled = true;
                        deleteButton.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot place a ship part on this position. Please try again.");
            }
        }

        private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentShipLabel.Text = "Click on any part of the ship you want to delete.";
            foreach (var ship in placedShips)
            {
                foreach (var position in ship.Positions)
                {
                    tableButtons[position.X, position.Y].Click += DeleteShipClick;
                }
            }
        }

        private void DeleteShipClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
            if (clickedButton == null)
                return;

            int x = clickedButton.Location.X / 30;
            int y = clickedButton.Location.Y / 30;

            Ship shipToDelete = null;

            foreach (var ship in placedShips)
            {
                if (ship.Positions.Contains(new Point(x, y)))
                {
                    shipToDelete = ship;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (shipToDelete != null)
            {
                DeleteShip(shipToDelete);
                currentShipLabel.Text = $"Place a ship of size {shipToDelete.Size}";
                currentShip = shipToDelete;
                currentShipIndex = ships.IndexOf(shipToDelete);

                foreach (var position in shipToDelete.Positions)
                {
                    tableButtons[position.X, position.Y].Click -= DeleteShipClick;
                }
            }

            deleteButton.Enabled = placedShips.Count > 0;
        }

        private void DeleteShip(Ship ship)
        {
            foreach (var position in ship.Positions)
            {
                tableButtons[position.X, position.Y].BackColor = default(Color);
                tableButtons[position.X, position.Y].Enabled = true;
            }
            placedShips.Remove(ship);
            ships.Insert(currentShipIndex, ship); // Return the ship to the list for re-placement
        }

        private void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void SetCurrentShip()
        {
            currentShip = ships[currentShipIndex];
            currentShip.Positions.Clear();
            currentShipLabel.Text = $"Place a ship of size {currentShip.Size}";
            deleteButton.Enabled = placedShips.Count > 0;
        }

        private bool CanPlaceShipPart(int x, int y)
        {
            if (tableButtons[x, y].BackColor == Color.Gray)
                return false; // The field is already taken

            // Check continuity of ship placement
            if (currentShip.Positions.Count > 0)
            {
                var lastPos = currentShip.Positions[currentShip.Positions.Count - 1];

                // Check if the second part of the ship can be placed next to the first one
                bool validHorizontalPos = (x == lastPos.X && Math.Abs(y - lastPos.Y) == 1);
                bool validVerticalPos = (y == lastPos.Y && Math.Abs(x - lastPos.X) == 1);

                if (validHorizontalPos || validVerticalPos)
                {
                    // Check if the adjacent field is taken
                    foreach (var (dx, dy) in new[] { (-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1) })
                    {
                        int nx = x + dx;
                        int ny = y + dy;

                        if (nx >= 0 && nx < tableSize && ny >= 0 && ny < tableSize)
                        {
                            if (tableButtons[nx, ny].BackColor == Color.Gray)
                                return false; // The adjacent field is taken
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private void PlaceShipPart(int x, int y)
        {
            tableButtons[x, y].BackColor = Color.Gray; // Color the field gray
            tableButtons[x, y].Enabled = false; // Disable clicking on the same field again
        }

        private Label currentShipLabel;
        private Button confirmButton;
        private Button deleteButton;
    }
}


Thank you for your time.
PS: sorry if I am grammatically incorrect somewhere, English is not my native language

Using the debugger to step through CanPlaceShipPart will help you find the problem

The following may be of interest: Tutorial: Debug a .NET console application using Visual Studio

The manner in which you've written your code makes it more difficult to debug, unless one uses the debugger. I typically use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine for debugging. However, code such as this: bool validHorizontalPos = (x == lastPos.X && Math.Abs(y - lastPos.Y) == 1); will have to be rewritten (ie: store the values in variables). Also, an hour of debugging may be insufficient. You may have just as well said that you spent 30 seconds debugging and couldn't find the issue. Keep trying.
